# UIView misplaced every time it's rotated

Tags: swift, uiview, rotation

I'm having a ruler (red) and a UIView (orange) below it like this:

[image]

When I rotate the ruler, the UIView rotates as well but it's location is not what I expected:

[image]

I use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to rotate the ruler, when I hold finger and move, I got an `angle` to re-draw the ruler and it worked perfectly but not for the UIView.

How I create and rotate the UIView:

```
 func createUIViewOutSideRuler(touchedPoint:CGPoint, notTouchedPoint:CGPoint, angle: CGFloat) -> UIView{
        let viewWidth = distanceFromTwoPoints(touchedPoint, notTouchedPoint)

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:notTouchedPoint.x, y: notTouchedPoint.y , width:  viewWidth, height: dotLineSize * 2))
        
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle);

        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
```

**Update base on Sweeper comment**

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:notTouchedPoint.x, y: notTouchedPoint.y , width:  viewWidth, height: dotLineSize * 2))
        
let vectorToStartPoint = CGPoint(x: view.center.x - touchedPoint.x,
                                         y: view.center.y - touchedPoint.y )
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: vectorToStartPoint.x, y: vectorToStartPoint.y)
                             .rotated(by: angle)
                             .translatedBy(x: -vectorToStartPoint.x, y: -vectorToStartPoint.y)
```

Result:

**Note**: I drag the `touchedPoint` to rotate

Center around `touchedPoint`
[image]

Center around `notTouchedPoint`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to rotate the view around `notTouchedPoint`. By default, a rotation created with `CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle:)` will rotate the view around its centre.

To do this, first translate the centre of the view to `startPoint`, rotate it, then translate it back.

```
let vectorToNotTouchedPoint = CGPoint(x: view.center.x - notTouchedPoint.x
                                      y: view.center.y - notTouchedPoint.y)
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: vectorToNotTouchedPoint.x, y: vectorToNotTouchedPoint.y)
                     .rotated(by: angle)
                     .translatedBy(x: -vectorToNotTouchedPoint.x, y: -vectorToNotTouchedPoint.y)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I updated my question base on your answer with result picture, assuming `startPoint` is `notTouchedPoint`

Comment: @baole Why did you replace `startPoint` with `notTouchPoint`/`touchedPoint`? When I say `startPoint`, I mean `startPoint` the parameter.

Comment: `startPoint` the parameter is `touchedPoint`, I just changed the name for clearer context. Before I changed the name, I used exactly like what u said with `startPoint` the param and the result is the last picture

Comment: sorry, `startPoint` is supposed to be `touchedPoint`

Comment: @baole That is not "clearer context". I am telling you to change the implementation of `createUIViewOutSideRuler`, and replacing `startPoint` with `notTouchedPoint` makes it seem like you have instead changed the caller instead. Anyway, can you show the action for the gesture recogniser?

Comment: so sorry for the late respone, because my gesture action has a bunch of unrelated thing so I'll sum up like this: `.case begin` gets `gpoint` of `notTouchedPoint`, `.case changed` does `let tempAngle = atan2(currentPanPoint.y - notTouchedPoint.y, currentPanPoint.x - notTouchedPoint.x)`, which shows me the angle from my finger to `notTouchedPoint`, `.case ended` redraw a straight ruler from `notTouchedPoint` to `currentPanPoint` then rotate it by `tempAngle`, then rotate `UIView` as I mentioned in my post

Comment: @baole Hmm, that looks alright... I am out of ideas then. :-( Let's wait for someone else and see if they can answer :-)